# Unable to import Active Directory module using powershell

Tags: powershell, import-module

I am trying to create a security group but before that i need to import Active Directory module in powershell.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

But above script gives an error as "Import-Module : The specified module 'ActiveDirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory." Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: did you install the feature via the Server Manager? RSAT includes AD powershell tools

Comment: @Jawad...How to install Server Manager?

Comment: All windows servers come with server manager

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the RSAT tools. You can do this by opening an elevated powershell window

```
DISM.exe /Online /add-capability /CapabilityName:Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.BitLocker.Recovery.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.CertificateServices.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.DHCP.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.Dns.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.FailoverCluster.Management.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.FileServices.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.GroupPolicy.Management.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.IPAM.Client.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.LLDP.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.NetworkController.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.NetworkLoadBalancing.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.RemoteAccess.Management.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.RemoteDesktop.Services.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.ServerManager.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.Shielded.VM.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.StorageReplica.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.VolumeActivation.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.WSUS.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.StorageMigrationService.Management.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0 /CapabilityName:Rsat.SystemInsights.Management.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0
```